# Como Utilizar o "Not Exists" no LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, query

Estou tentando traduzir a consulta abaixo, em LINQ, porém sem sucesso, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
SELECT * FROM PESSOAL A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Chapa FROM PRODUCAO B 
    WHERE B.Chapa = A.Chapa AND B.Data='2014-09-02') 
AND A.Codsubord='CB02010100';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Experimenta:

```
db.Pessoal.where(a => !db.Producao.Any(b => b.Chapa == a.Chapa && b.Data == new DateTime(2014, 09, 02)) && a.Codsubord== "CB02010100");
```

Assim, estou a ir buscar todos os dados da tabela `Pessoa` (`SELECT * FROM PESSOAL`), onde não estejam os dados da `Producao` que pretendes. Parar tal uso o `!db.Producao.Any(...)` para fazer o `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: tenho dificuldade com expressões lambda e tentei experimentar mas o visual retornou erros

Comment: e que erro foi?